# Get variable from another file - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a Tkinter program that allows the user to enter text into a nice looking box rather than the python shell.

As I would like to use this in multiple programs I made into a function that can be used in other files.

I can get it to run in another file, but not import the variable here is my code.

File 1:

```
import tkinter as tk

def input_text(label_text, button_text):
    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
            self.button = tk.Button(self, text=button_text, command=self.on_button)
            self.label = tk.Label(self, text=label_text)
            self.label.pack(side = 'top', pady = 5)
            self.button.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 5)
            self.entry.pack()


        def on_button(self):
            answer = self.entry.get()
            self.destroy()


    w = SampleApp()
    w.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    w.geometry('{}x{}'.format(180, 90))
    w.mainloop()
```

File 2:

```
import text_input as ti
from text_input import answer
ti.input_text('Enter some text', 'OK')
```

I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'answer'`

Comment: You don't seem to be saving 'answer' anywhere, so it doesn't exist outside the function `on_button`. I think there's probably a better way to do this - not having the class and control code in the same function, for example.

Comment: There is no "answer" in file 1

Comment: Yes there is it is in the last function(at the bottom)

Comment: @SimonFraser How could I save answer elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`answer is a local variable within`button`.  If you want to`import` it, you need to make it a package attribute:

```
import tkinter as tk

global answer

def input_text(label_text, button_text):
    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    ...

        def on_button(self):
            global answer
            answer = self.entry.get()
```

However, this is a *very* strange way to access the data.  Clean module design would likely have the *object* (SampleApp) at hand, and extract the answer with a method call for that app.  More simply, why not just return that value from `on_button`?

```
    def on_button(self):
        answer = self.entry.get()
        self.destroy()
        return answer
```

... so your usage would be

```
response = my_app.on_button()
```